# Is there a simple function mapping -1 to 1 and 1 to 0

Tags: elementary-functions, simple-functions

This is a rather simple question.

I'm writing a computer program, and I have a variable for velocity, which takes values  $\pm 1$. I also have corresponding sprites, facing both right and left, on rows `0` and `1` of a spritesheet. Funny enough, I got the rows on the sheet backwards, so the leftwards is in the first row, and rightwards in the second row. What I'm trying to do is map `-1` to `1` and `1` to `0`.

So my question is: is there a simple function $f$ constructed from standard computer math like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, absolute value, floors and ceilings that satisfies $f(-1) = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Why not $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $x=-1$, and} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=1$.} \end{cases} $$  This seems likely to be more computationally efficient than the formula you suggest in your answer...

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1-x}2$

Comment: I think you mean abs() of that expression

Comment: @Mathchiller Read it more carefully.  If $x = -1$, then $f(-1) = \frac{1-(-1)}{2} = \frac{2}{2} = 1$, as desired.  Similarly, $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: The most obvious approach is polynomial interpolation (works for any number of points , if the $x$-values are pairwise distinct). I do no think that a simpler function is possible. "Simple" is anyway somewhat opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the points $(-1,1)$ and $(1,0)$. We can simply construct the line that goes through these points:

$y=\frac{1-x}{2}$

Does that work for your purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Since you said computer program, you may also use
$$f(x) = 0 ^ {1 + x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

One solution possible might be $f(x) = |(\text{floor}\frac{x}{2})|$